# GoのGoroutine について教えて下さい。

Tags: go, goroutine

Goroutineを使って下記プログラムを作成しました。(Playgroundで実行できませんがローカルではできます)
https://play.golang.org/p/5IdzS4FAtp

しかし、これはでスタックしてしまいます。
このようなプログラムをスタックせずに実行するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

プログラム

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    msgCh := make(chan string)
    count := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < 255; i++ {
        go first(msgCh)
    }

L:
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-msgCh:
            count++
            fmt.Printf("%f:%s\n", count, msg)
            if count == 4294967296 {
                break L
            }
        default:
        }
    }

}

func first(msgCh chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 255; i++ {
        go second(msgCh)
    }
}

func second(msgCh chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 255; i++ {
        go third(msgCh)
    }
}

func third(msgCh chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 255; i++ {
        msgCh <- "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: 何がしたいのかプログラムから読み取れないので正しい回答が得られないかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問欄にあるプログラムを以下の環境で実行してみました。

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v3 @ 2.60GHz
- コア数: 8 (with Hyper-Threading)
- メモリ: 64 GB
- OS: CentOS Linux 7.0
- Golang version: devel +b2963a5

まず、メモリの使用量なのですが、最大で 41 GB にもなります。lightweight とはいえ、255*255*255 個の goroutine を生成していますので仕方のない事なのでしょう。また、途中までの経過時間から線形外挿すると実行時間は 250 分程度(4時間強)になるかと思われます。

そんなわけで goroutine の最大同時実行数を 255 として、かつ、channel を `[255]string` 型にして channel に対する入出力の回数を減らしてみました。

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
)
import "runtime"

const msgLen int = 255

type helloString [msgLen]string
type helloChannel chan helloString

func main() {
  runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
  msgCh := make(helloChannel)

  for i := 0; i < msgLen*msgLen; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < msgLen; j++ {
      go third(msgCh)
    }

    for j := 0; j < msgLen; j++ {
      for k, msg := 0, <-msgCh; k < msgLen; k++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %s\n", i*msgLen*msgLen+j*msgLen+k, msg[k])
      }
    }
  }
  close(msgCh)
}

func third(msgCh helloChannel) {
  var hello helloString
  for i := 0; i < msgLen; i++ {
    hello[i] = "Hello"
  }
  msgCh <- hello
}
```

最大メモリ使用量は 30 MB 弱、実行時間は 47分 でした。

# まぁ、あまり効果はないですね。。。

Comment: わざわざためして頂いて恐縮です。goroutineを使えばいいということではないのですね。
一番外側のfor文をCPU数で水平分割してgoroutineを作成したところ高速化できました。

Answer (score -1):

Channelを閉じてないので永久にblockしてます。計算が終わった時点でchannelを閉じてやりましょう。

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    msgCh := make(chan string)
    count := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go first(msgCh)
    }

    done := false
    for {
        select {
        case msg, ok := <-msgCh:
            if !ok {
                done = true
                break
            }
            count++
            fmt.Printf("%f:%s\n", count, msg)
            if count == 16 {
                close(msgCh)
            }
        }

        if done {
            break
        }
    }

}

func first(msgCh chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go second(msgCh)
    }
}

func second(msgCh chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go third(msgCh)
    }
}

func third(msgCh chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        msgCh <- "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: そもそも計算が終わる前にスタックしているのでチャネルの閉じる閉じないは別問題では。。。

Comment: Go routineの数が多過ぎなのが原因かと。

Comment: そうかもしれません。試しに最後のgoroutineを消したところ、動きました。しかし、ベンチマークの結果goroutineを回しても速くなるどころか遅くなってしまいました。回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決したなら解決済みにしておいて下さい :)